# Show that, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $\sqrt{z^2}=\sqrt{x^2}+\frac{x}{|x|}yi$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I would like to show that, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $\sqrt{z^2}=\sqrt{x^2}+\frac{x}{|x|}yi$.

What I have is, for $z=x+yi$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,

$\sqrt{z^2}=z$ if $x>0$ or if $x=0$ and $y \geq 0$ OR
$\sqrt{z^2}=-z$ if $x<0$ or if $x=0$ and $y<0$.

I also have $z^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi$.

The part that I’m having difficulty with is deriving the following equality, which is the last step I need to prove my initial equality:

$\sqrt{z^2}=\sqrt{x^2}+\frac{xy}{|xy|}\sqrt{y^2}i$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps splitting into cases where -π<Arg(z)<0 and 0<Arg(z)<π will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Recall that for a real number $x$, $\vert x\vert=\sqrt{x^2}$ and that for $x\ne0$, $\dfrac{x}{\vert x\vert}=\dfrac{\vert x\vert}{x}$.

Let $z=\vert z\vert(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. Then $z^2=\vert z\vert^2(\cos2\theta+i\sin2\theta)$.

$z^2$ will have two square roots

$$ w=\pm(\vert z\vert(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta))=\pm(x+yi)$$

But the principle square root of a complex number is the root with non-negative real part. So

$$\sqrt{z^2}=\dfrac{x}{\vert x\vert}(x+yi)=\vert x\vert+\dfrac{x}{\vert x\vert}\cdot yi=\sqrt{x^2}+\dfrac{x}{\vert x\vert}\cdot yi$$

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions: why did the $\pm$ become $\frac{x}{|x|}$? Also, can’t we take principle square root of a complex number with negative real parts, as long as it’s imaginary part is not 0?

Comment: $x/|x|$ is more precise than $\pm$ because it tell for which values of $x$ it is $+$ and for which values of $x$ for which it is $-$. The two square roots of a complex number (whether or not its real part is negative ) which is not a pure imaginary will always have one root where the real part is positive and one where the real part is negative. The one where the real part is positive is the *principle* square root. Note that this formula is only valid when the real part is not $0$.

Comment: I’m still confused, but I really appreciate your help. I should be more specific for my question: if $x < 0$, then $\frac{x}{|x|}=-1$ and $\sqrt{z^2}=x-yi$ which is neither $\pm (x+yi)$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you are confusing two different issues. Give me a few minutes and I will add an example to my answer which may help you to understand.

Comment: It may be easier to answer in a comment than adding an example. If we have $x+yi$ and $x<0$, then $\frac{|x|}{x}(x-iy)=|x|+\frac{|x|}{x}yi$ so the real part will be positive even though $x$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring your expression gives:
$$z^2=x^2-y^2+2\sqrt{x^2}\frac{x}{|x|}y i$$ with $$z=x+iy$$ we get
$$x^2-y^2+2xyi=x^2-y^2+2\sqrt{x^2}\frac{x}{|x|}y i$$
after simplifications we get
$$2xy i=2\sqrt{x^2}\frac{x}{|x|}y i$$ this is the same only for $$x\neq 0$$